# How to ingest multiple csv files into a Spark dataframe?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, data-ingestion

I am trying to ingest 2 csv files into a single spark dataframe. However, the schema of these 2 datasets is very different, and when I perform the below operation, I get back only the schema of the second csv, as if the first one doesn't exist. How can I solve this? My final goal is to count the total number of words.

paths = ["abfss://lmne.dfs.core.windows.net/csvs/MachineLearning_reddit.csv",     "abfss://test1@lmne.dfs.core.windows.net/csvs/bbc_news.csv"]

```
df0_spark=spark.read.format("csv").option("header","false").load(paths)
df0_spark.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("ML_reddit2")
df0_spark.show()
```

I tried to load both of the files into a single spark dataframe, but it only gives me back one of the tables.

Comment: how different are the schemas?

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced the above and got the below results.

For sample, I have two csv files in dbfs with different schemas. when I execute the above code, I got the same result.

[image]

To get the desired schema enable `mergeSchema`and `header` while reading the files.

**Code:**

```
df0_spark=spark.read.format("csv").option("mergeSchema","true").option("header","true").load(paths)
df0_spark.show()
```

[image]

If you want to combine the two files without nulls, we should have a common identity column and we have to read the files individually and use inner join for that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that has worked for me the best in such cases was to read all *distinct* files separately, and then union them after they have been put into DataFrames. So your code could look something like this:

```py
paths = ["abfss://lmne.dfs.core.windows.net/csvs/MachineLearning_reddit.csv", "abfss://test1@lmne.dfs.core.windows.net/csvs/bbc_news.csv"]

# Load all distinct CSV files
df1 = spark.read.option("header", false).csv(paths[0])
df2 = spark.read.option("header", false).csv(paths[1])

# Union DataFrames
combined_df = df1.unionByName(df2, allowMissingColumns=True)
```

**Note**: if the names of columns differ between the files, then for all columns from first file that are not present in second one, you will have `null` values. If the schema should be matching, then you can always rename the columns, before the `unionByName` step.